# TypeScript double class property initialization syntax

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I am a relatively experienced JavaScript developer but I can't quite get my head around this TypeScript syntax with the double initializing of class properties. Why? Why is the type checked twice? Is the greeting property before the constructor a static property of the class while the property in constructor for instances? I would be very grateful if someone can clear this up for me since the documentation doesn't seem to speak about it.

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}

let greeter = new Greeter("world");
```

Comment: `greeting: string` declares that this property will exist on the class and what type it will have. The part in the `constructor` assigns it its initial value at construction time.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for clearing it up! Just one more question, will the property be static as well?

Comment: No, because you didn't declare it using the `static` keyword.

Comment: @deceze great, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`greeting: string` declares that this property will exist on the class and what type it will have. The part in the `constructor` assigns it its initial value at time of instantiation.

If you skip the `greeting: string` declaration, TypeScript will complain whenever you try to access `this.greeting`. This helps catch typos, e.g. if you tried to access `this.grooting`, TypeScript could tell you that this doesn't seem right as `grooting` isn't supposed to exist on the class.

Note that there's a shorthand for exactly your declare-and-initialise use case:

```
class Greeter {
    constructor(protected greeting: string) {}

    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
```

This behaves exactly the same with less redundancy.

Comment: Very concise answer that helped me right away. Thank you kind sir :)

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question correctly, you're talking about the variable typing.

Variable types are using for data modeling purposes, or locking value types. That's the easy way to explain it.

When you type a variable as a string, it stores that value as a string in the memory and says that only that value type can be passed, or assigned to this specific argument or variable. In your example, `greeting: string;` can only be stored as a string and nothing else. In the `constructor`, it will only accept an initial argument of type string.